# Help in applying the boundaries of an elliptic integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need urgent help in determining the final result of the definite integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left (b\cos(x) + \sqrt{a^2 - b^2\sin^2(x)}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x.$$
I know, by using an online integral calculator, the indefinite integral gives:

$$|a| E\left(x\left|\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right.\right) + b \sin(x) + C$$

But, since it is an elliptical integral (of the second kind with parameter $m=k^2$), which is out of the scope of the mathematics I have studied and been familiar with, I cannot literally do anything about it.

Could someone, acquainted with elliptic integrals, apply the boundaries of the integral for me, please?

Please, I need this so badly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not explain why it is "urgent" and why you "need this so badly". Could you please elaborate a bit on those points?

Comment: Because I need this integral in solving a physics problem for myself, which has to do with the Biot-Savart law and, in another problem, the magnetic force on a wire. It is an integral that I cannot deal with, since it is out of the scope of my maths. I abandoned the problem bacause I could not find anyone I know to perform the integral fully and online integral calculators could not determine the result of the definite integral,  but I see I now need to complete it and it would be helpful to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^2x}\,dx=4|a|\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-(b/a)^2\sin^2x}\,dx=4|a|E(k=b/a)$$
and this is the *complete* elliptic integral. The other term in the original integral evaluates to zero, so the final answer is
$$4|a|E(b/a)$$